# How to write a matrix matrix product that can compete with Eigen?

Tags: c++, matrix, matrix-multiplication, eigen

Below is the C++ implementation comparing the time taken by Eigen and For Loop to perform matrix-matrix products. The For loop has been optimised to minimise cache misses. The for loop is faster than Eigen initially but then eventually becomes slower (upto a factor of 2 for 500 by 500 matrices). What else should I do to compete with Eigen? Is blocking the reason for the better Eigen performance? If so, how should I go about adding  blocking to the for loop?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Eigen/Dense>
#include<ctime>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    //  Input the size of the matrix from the user
    int N   =   atoi(argv[1]);

    int M   =   N*N;

    //  The matrices stored as row-wise vectors
    double a[M];
    double b[M];
    double c[M];

    //  Initializing Eigen Matrices
    Eigen::MatrixXd a_E =   Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(N,N);
    Eigen::MatrixXd b_E =   Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(N,N);
    Eigen::MatrixXd c_E(N,N);

    double CPS  =   CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    clock_t start, end;


    //  Matrix vector product by Eigen
    start   =   clock();
    c_E     =   a_E*b_E;
    end     =   clock();

    std::cout << "\nTime taken by Eigen is: " << (end-start)/CPS << "\n";

    //  Initializing For loop vectors
    int count   =   0;
    for (int j=0; j<N; ++j) {
        for (int k=0; k<N; ++k) {
            a[count]    =   a_E(j,k);
            b[count]    =   b_E(j,k);
            ++count;
        }
    }

    //  Matrix vector product by For loop
    start   =   clock();
    count   =   0;
    int count1, count2;
    for (int j=0; j<N; ++j) {
        count1  =   j*N;
        for (int k=0; k<N; ++k) {
            c[count]    =   a[count1]*b[k];
            ++count;
        }
    }

    for (int j=0; j<N; ++j) {
        count2  =   N;
        for (int l=1; l<N; ++l) {
            count   =   j*N;
            count1  =   count+l;
            for (int k=0; k<N; ++k) {
                c[count]+=a[count1]*b[count2];
                ++count;
                ++count2;
            }
        }
    }
    end     =   clock();

    std::cout << "\nTime taken by for-loop is: " << (end-start)/CPS << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial which shows how to speed up the matrix-matrix product: [GEMM: From Pure C to SSE Optimized Micro Kernels](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/sghpc/gemm/)

Comment: Based on the same concept, I also showed how the the matrix-matrix in boost::ublas could get pimped up here: [Matrix-Matrix Product Experiments with uBLAS](http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/test_ublas/index.html) and [Matrix-Matrix Product Experiments with BLAZE](http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/test_blaze/index.html).  It starts with a "pure C++" implementation.  Besides using assembly code for doing the vectorization, it also contains an example using the GCC  vector extensions.

Comment: Because the above link is dead, here is a working one: [GEMM: From Pure C to SSE Optimized Micro Kernels](https://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/sghpc/gemm)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no need to mystifying how a high performance implementation of the matrix-matrix product can be achieved.  In fact we need more people knowing about it, in order to face future challenges in high-performance computing.  In order to get into this topic reading [BLIS: A Framework for Rapidly Instantiating BLAS Functionality](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/flame/pubs/blis1_toms_rev3.pdf) is a good starting point.

So in order to demystify and to answer the question (How to write a matrix matrix product that can compete with Eigen) I extended the code posted by ggael to a total of 400 lines.  I just tested it on an AVX machine (Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz).  Here some results:

```
g++-5.3 -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++11 -mavx -m64 -I ../eigen.3.2.8/ gemm.cc -lrt

lehn@heim:~/work/test_eigen$ ./a.out 500
Time taken by Eigen is: 0.0190425
Time taken by for-loop is: 0.0121688

lehn@heim:~/work/test_eigen$ ./a.out 1000
Time taken by Eigen is: 0.147991
Time taken by for-loop is: 0.0959097

lehn@heim:~/work/test_eigen$ ./a.out 1500
Time taken by Eigen is: 0.492858
Time taken by for-loop is: 0.322442

lehn@heim:~/work/test_eigen$ ./a.out 5000
Time taken by Eigen is: 18.3666
Time taken by for-loop is: 12.1023
```

If you have FMA you can compile with

```
g++-5.3 -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++11 -mfma -m64 -I ../eigen.3.2.8/ -DHAVE_FMA gemm.cc -lrt
```

If you also want multithreading with openMP also compile with `-fopenmp`

Here the complete code based on the ideas of the BLIS paper.  It is self-contained except that it needs the complete Eigen source files as ggael already noted:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Eigen/Dense>
#include<bench/BenchTimer.h>
#if defined(_OPENMP)
#include <omp.h>
#endif
//-- malloc with alignment --------------------------------------------------------
void *
malloc_(std::size_t alignment, std::size_t size)
{
    alignment = std::max(alignment, alignof(void *));
    size     += alignment;

    void *ptr  = std::malloc(size);
    void *ptr2 = (void *)(((uintptr_t)ptr + alignment) & ~(alignment-1));
    void **vp  = (void**) ptr2 - 1;
    *vp        = ptr;
    return ptr2;
}

void
free_(void *ptr)
{
    std::free(*((void**)ptr-1));
}

//-- Config --------------------------------------------------------------------

// SIMD-Register width in bits
// SSE:         128
// AVX/FMA:     256
// AVX-512:     512
#ifndef SIMD_REGISTER_WIDTH
#define SIMD_REGISTER_WIDTH 256
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_FMA

#   ifndef BS_D_MR
#   define BS_D_MR 4
#   endif

#   ifndef BS_D_NR
#   define BS_D_NR 12
#   endif

#   ifndef BS_D_MC
#   define BS_D_MC 256
#   endif

#   ifndef BS_D_KC
#   define BS_D_KC 512
#   endif

#   ifndef BS_D_NC
#   define BS_D_NC 4092
#   endif

#endif



#ifndef BS_D_MR
#define BS_D_MR 4
#endif

#ifndef BS_D_NR
#define BS_D_NR 8
#endif

#ifndef BS_D_MC
#define BS_D_MC 256
#endif

#ifndef BS_D_KC
#define BS_D_KC 256
#endif

#ifndef BS_D_NC
#define BS_D_NC 4096
#endif

template <typename T>
struct BlockSize
{
    static constexpr int MC = 64;
    static constexpr int KC = 64;
    static constexpr int NC = 256;
    static constexpr int MR = 8;
    static constexpr int NR = 8;

    static constexpr int rwidth = 0;
    static constexpr int align  = alignof(T);
    static constexpr int vlen   = 0;

    static_assert(MC>0 && KC>0 && NC>0 && MR>0 && NR>0, "Invalid block size.");
    static_assert(MC % MR == 0, "MC must be a multiple of MR.");
    static_assert(NC % NR == 0, "NC must be a multiple of NR.");
};


template <>
struct BlockSize<double>
{
    static constexpr int MC     = BS_D_MC;
    static constexpr int KC     = BS_D_KC;
    static constexpr int NC     = BS_D_NC;
    static constexpr int MR     = BS_D_MR;
    static constexpr int NR     = BS_D_NR;

    static constexpr int rwidth = SIMD_REGISTER_WIDTH;
    static constexpr int align  = rwidth / 8;
    static constexpr int vlen   = rwidth / (8*sizeof(double));

    static_assert(MC>0 && KC>0 && NC>0 && MR>0 && NR>0, "Invalid block size.");
    static_assert(MC % MR == 0, "MC must be a multiple of MR.");
    static_assert(NC % NR == 0, "NC must be a multiple of NR.");
    static_assert(rwidth % sizeof(double) == 0, "SIMD register width not sane.");
};

//-- aux routines --------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Index, typename Alpha, typename TX, typename TY>
void
geaxpy(Index m, Index n,
       const Alpha &alpha,
       const TX *X, Index incRowX, Index incColX,
       TY       *Y, Index incRowY, Index incColY)
{
    for (Index j=0; j<n; ++j) {
        for (Index i=0; i<m; ++i) {
            Y[i*incRowY+j*incColY] += alpha*X[i*incRowX+j*incColX];
        }
    }
}

template <typename Index, typename Alpha, typename TX>
void
gescal(Index m, Index n,
       const Alpha &alpha,
       TX *X, Index incRowX, Index incColX)
{
    if (alpha!=Alpha(0)) {
        for (Index j=0; j<n; ++j) {
            for (Index i=0; i<m; ++i) {
                X[i*incRowX+j*incColX] *= alpha;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (Index j=0; j<n; ++j) {
            for (Index i=0; i<m; ++i) {
                X[i*incRowX+j*incColX] = Alpha(0);
            }
        }
    }
}


//-- Micro Kernel --------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Index, typename T>
typename std::enable_if<BlockSize<T>::vlen != 0,
         void>::type
ugemm(Index kc, T alpha, const T *A, const T *B, T beta,
      T *C, Index incRowC, Index incColC)
{
    typedef T vx __attribute__((vector_size (BlockSize<T>::rwidth/8)));

    static constexpr Index vlen = BlockSize<T>::vlen;
    static constexpr Index MR   = BlockSize<T>::MR;
    static constexpr Index NR   = BlockSize<T>::NR/vlen;

    A = (const T*) __builtin_assume_aligned (A, BlockSize<T>::align);
    B = (const T*) __builtin_assume_aligned (B, BlockSize<T>::align);

    vx P[MR*NR] = {};

    for (Index l=0; l<kc; ++l) {
        const vx *b = (const vx *)B;
        for (Index i=0; i<MR; ++i) {
            for (Index j=0; j<NR; ++j) {
                P[i*NR+j] += A[i]*b[j];
            }
        }
        A += MR;
        B += vlen*NR;
    }

    if (alpha!=T(1)) {
        for (Index i=0; i<MR; ++i) {
            for (Index j=0; j<NR; ++j) {
                P[i*NR+j] *= alpha;
            }
        }
    }

    if (beta!=T(0)) {
        for (Index i=0; i<MR; ++i) {
            for (Index j=0; j<NR; ++j) {
                const T *p = (const T *) &P[i*NR+j];
                for (Index j1=0; j1<vlen; ++j1) {
                    C[i*incRowC+(j*vlen+j1)*incColC] *= beta;
                    C[i*incRowC+(j*vlen+j1)*incColC] += p[j1];
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (Index i=0; i<MR; ++i) {
            for (Index j=0; j<NR; ++j) {
                const T *p = (const T *) &P[i*NR+j];
                for (Index j1=0; j1<vlen; ++j1) {
                    C[i*incRowC+(j*vlen+j1)*incColC] = p[j1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//-- Macro Kernel --------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Index, typename T, typename Beta, typename TC>
void
mgemm(Index mc, Index nc, Index kc,
      T alpha,
      const T *A, const T *B,
      Beta beta,
      TC *C, Index incRowC, Index incColC)
{
    const Index MR = BlockSize<T>::MR;
    const Index NR = BlockSize<T>::NR;
    const Index mp  = (mc+MR-1) / MR;
    const Index np  = (nc+NR-1) / NR;
    const Index mr_ = mc % MR;
    const Index nr_ = nc % NR;

    T C_[MR*NR];

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (Index j=0; j<np; ++j) {
        const Index nr = (j!=np-1 || nr_==0) ? NR : nr_;

        for (Index i=0; i<mp; ++i) {
            const Index mr = (i!=mp-1 || mr_==0) ? MR : mr_;

            if (mr==MR && nr==NR) {
                ugemm(kc, alpha,
                      &A[i*kc*MR], &B[j*kc*NR],
                      beta,
                      &C[i*MR*incRowC+j*NR*incColC],
                      incRowC, incColC);
            } else {
                ugemm(kc, alpha,
                      &A[i*kc*MR], &B[j*kc*NR],
                      T(0),
                      C_, Index(1), MR);
                gescal(mr, nr, beta,
                       &C[i*MR*incRowC+j*NR*incColC],
                       incRowC, incColC);
                geaxpy(mr, nr, T(1), C_, Index(1), MR,
                       &C[i*MR*incRowC+j*NR*incColC],
                       incRowC, incColC);
            }
        }
    }
}
//-- Packing blocks ------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Index, typename TA, typename T>
void
pack_A(Index mc, Index kc,
       const TA *A, Index incRowA, Index incColA,
       T *p)
{
    Index MR = BlockSize<T>::MR;
    Index mp = (mc+MR-1) / MR;

    for (Index j=0; j<kc; ++j) {
        for (Index l=0; l<mp; ++l) {
            for (Index i0=0; i0<MR; ++i0) {
                Index i  = l*MR + i0;
                Index nu = l*MR*kc + j*MR + i0;
                p[nu]   = (i<mc) ? A[i*incRowA+j*incColA]
                                 : T(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

template <typename Index, typename TB, typename T>
void
pack_B(Index kc, Index nc,
       const TB *B, Index incRowB, Index incColB,
       T *p)
{
    Index NR = BlockSize<T>::NR;
    Index np = (nc+NR-1) / NR;

    for (Index l=0; l<np; ++l) {
        for (Index j0=0; j0<NR; ++j0) {
            for (Index i=0; i<kc; ++i) {
                Index j  = l*NR+j0;
                Index nu = l*NR*kc + i*NR + j0;
                p[nu]   = (j<nc) ? B[i*incRowB+j*incColB]
                                 : T(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
//-- Frame routine -------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Index, typename Alpha,
         typename TA, typename TB,
         typename Beta,
         typename TC>
void
gemm(Index m, Index n, Index k,
     Alpha alpha,
     const TA *A, Index incRowA, Index incColA,
     const TB *B, Index incRowB, Index incColB,
     Beta beta,
     TC *C, Index incRowC, Index incColC)
{
    typedef typename std::common_type<Alpha, TA, TB>::type  T;

    const Index MC = BlockSize<T>::MC;
    const Index NC = BlockSize<T>::NC;
    const Index MR = BlockSize<T>::MR;
    const Index NR = BlockSize<T>::NR;

    const Index KC = BlockSize<T>::KC;
    const Index mb = (m+MC-1) / MC;
    const Index nb = (n+NC-1) / NC;
    const Index kb = (k+KC-1) / KC;
    const Index mc_ = m % MC;
    const Index nc_ = n % NC;
    const Index kc_ = k % KC;

    T *A_ = (T*) malloc_(BlockSize<T>::align, sizeof(T)*(MC*KC+MR));
    T *B_ = (T*) malloc_(BlockSize<T>::align, sizeof(T)*(KC*NC+NR));

    if (alpha==Alpha(0) || k==0) {
        gescal(m, n, beta, C, incRowC, incColC);
        return;
    }

    for (Index j=0; j<nb; ++j) {
        Index nc = (j!=nb-1 || nc_==0) ? NC : nc_;

        for (Index l=0; l<kb; ++l) {
            Index   kc  = (l!=kb-1 || kc_==0) ? KC : kc_;
            Beta beta_  = (l==0) ? beta : Beta(1);

            pack_B(kc, nc,
                   &B[l*KC*incRowB+j*NC*incColB],
                   incRowB, incColB,
                   B_);

            for (Index i=0; i<mb; ++i) {
                Index mc = (i!=mb-1 || mc_==0) ? MC : mc_;

                pack_A(mc, kc,
                       &A[i*MC*incRowA+l*KC*incColA],
                       incRowA, incColA,
                       A_);

                mgemm(mc, nc, kc,
                      T(alpha), A_, B_, beta_,
                      &C[i*MC*incRowC+j*NC*incColC],
                      incRowC, incColC);
            }
        }
    }
    free_(A_);
    free_(B_);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void myprod(double *c, const double* a, const double* b, int N) {
    gemm(N, N, N, 1.0, a, 1, N, b, 1, N, 0.0, c, 1, N);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int N = atoi(argv[1]);
  int tries = 4;
  int rep = std::max<int>(1,10000000/N/N/N);

  Eigen::MatrixXd a_E = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(N,N);
  Eigen::MatrixXd b_E = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(N,N);
  Eigen::MatrixXd c_E(N,N);

  Eigen::BenchTimer t1, t2;

  BENCH(t1, tries, rep, c_E.noalias() = a_E*b_E );
  BENCH(t2, tries, rep, myprod(c_E.data(), a_E.data(), b_E.data(), N));

  std::cout << "Time taken by Eigen is: " << t1.best() << "\n";
  std::cout << "Time taken by for-loop is: " << t2.best() << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Your webpage is extremely useful! Interesting that you are able to beat Eigen! To clarify, does Eigen rely on BLAS? Also, could you let me know -mfma flag is for?

Comment: FMA stands for [fused-multiply-addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply–accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply.E2.80.93add).  It is supported by Intel starting with [Haswell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_(microarchitecture)).  With -fma the compiler will create instructions for it.

Comment: And no, Eigen does not rely on BLAS.

Comment: Thanks. Does Eigen then has its own BLAS equivalent or rely on an external BLAS like implementation? Sorry for asking too many question! More importantly, thanks for FLENS and ulmBLAS!

Comment: You are welcome to ask.  Eigen does not rely or depend on an external BLAS implementation.  You will also notice that when you compile a program using Eigen.  You don't have to link against an external library at all.

Comment: @Leg, last I checked Eigen only supported SSE. This answer uses AVX so in principle it should bet twice as fast. The kernel of my own GEMM codes is a bit less optimized than Eigen's but since it supports AVX and FMA it easily beats Eigen.

Comment: I like this answer. I am usually a big fan of letting code speak for itself but I still think you could have used a bit more text to describe the steps. I agree that more people should know how to optimized GEMM. It's a good lesson in palletization. It's also good learn that parallelization is a a lot of snake oil because large dense GEMM is one of the few things that is not necessarily memory bandwidth bound. Then again how useful is large dense GEMM in practice? Large sparse matrix mult. is far more useful in my experience. I think dense GEMM is mostly used for benchmarking.

Comment: The theoretical background is described in the (well written) BLIS paper.  About the application of dense matrix multiplication:  The performance of many dense numerical algorithms (LU, QR, SVD, Eigenvalues-/vectors) depends on it.  About sparse matrices.  Direct solvers for sparse equations again depend on fast dense-matrix products.  For iterative solvers the convergence depends on good pre conditioners.  Good pre conditioners again require fast dense-matrix products.  So the relevance of GEMM in applications might not be so obvious as it is in the lowest layer.

Comment: Also on [Matrix-Matrix Product Experiments with uBLAS](http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/test_ublas/index.html) I gave more insight on the algorithm as well as an example how it speeds up the LU factorization.

Comment: I did not see your comments until now because you did ping me (I mean with @Zboson)...I guess in the sparse matrix multiplication I have done the matrices were sparse enough that dense part is not so important. I think the [permutation matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603982/cholesky-decomposition-of-sparse-matrices-using-permutation-matrices) is far more important.

Comment: @Zboson Sure the algorithms for finding the permutation matrices in direct solvers like Pardiso (and all the others) are the most important stuff.  But again, all these libraries again depend on a fast BLAS.  It is anyway misleading when I say "most important".  It is the most important component on their layer.

Comment: @MichaelLehn What is the difference between FLENS and ulmBLAS. Is it just that FLENS is in C++ while ulmBLAS is in C? or is it more like BLAS and LAPACK? Again, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Your code is already well vectorized by the compiler. The key for higher performance is hierarchical blocking to optimize the usage of registers, and of the different level of caches. Partial loop unrolling is also crucial to improve instruction pipelining. Reaching the performance of Eigen's product require a lot of effort and tuning.

It should also be noted that your benchmark is slightly biased and not fully reliable. Here is a more reliable version (you need complete Eigen's sources to get `bench/BenchTimer.h`):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Eigen/Dense>
#include<bench/BenchTimer.h>

void myprod(double *c, const double* a, const double* b, int N) {
  int count = 0;
  int count1, count2;
  for (int j=0; j<N; ++j) {
      count1  =   j*N;
      for (int k=0; k<N; ++k) {
          c[count]    =   a[count1]*b[k];
          ++count;
      }
  }

  for (int j=0; j<N; ++j) {
      count2  =   N;
      for (int l=1; l<N; ++l) {
          count   =   j*N;
          count1  =   count+l;
          for (int k=0; k<N; ++k) {
              c[count]+=a[count1]*b[count2];
              ++count;
              ++count2;
          }
      }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int N = atoi(argv[1]);
  int tries = 4;
  int rep = std::max<int>(1,10000000/N/N/N);

  Eigen::MatrixXd a_E = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(N,N);
  Eigen::MatrixXd b_E = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(N,N);
  Eigen::MatrixXd c_E(N,N);

  Eigen::BenchTimer t1, t2;

  BENCH(t1, tries, rep, c_E.noalias() = a_E*b_E );
  BENCH(t2, tries, rep, myprod(c_E.data(), a_E.data(), b_E.data(), N));

  std::cout << "\nTime taken by Eigen is: " << t1.best() << "\n";
  std::cout << "\nTime taken by for-loop is: " << t2.best() << "\n";
}
```

Compiling with `3.3-beta1` and FMA enabled (`-mfma`), then the gap becomes much larger, almost one order of magnitude for `N=2000`.

Comment: Thanks as always! I tried on my machine with clang++ on ElCapitan and here are the timings in case it is of interest to you. For a 2000 by 2000 mat-mat product

Time taken by Eigen is: 1.08311

Time taken by for-loop is: 3.37003

Comment: Could you let me know what the -mfma flag is for?

Comment: I get the same with for-loop (3.36s) but only 0.36s with Eigen. I'm also using OSX and clang with `-O3 -DNDEBUG -mfma` and Eigen 3.3-beta1. `-mfma` enables AVX+FMA instructction sets. FMA stands for fused-multiply-add, and yields an additional x1.7 speedup.

Comment: I need to add a warning about FMA, which is really `fuse; multiply; then add`.  If you enable it on `gcc` as of this date, the compiler will drop what it views as algebraically insignificant parentheses.  This will generate code that violates the distributive law and as floating point is finite math it may impact your results.  Until gcc supports the `FP_CONTRACT` macro you will have to use another compiler or disable FMA if this behavior impacts you.

Comment: This can easily be mitigated by enabling FMA only in translation units for which this restructuring does not matter. I doubt anyone tightly mix such critical code with BLAS-like matrix-matrix products. Recall that two different BLAS implementation will return two different matrix-matrix product results for the same inputs (because the additions will be carried out in different orders).

Answer (score 2):

There are two simple optimizations that I may advice.

1) Vectorize it. It would be better if you vectorize it with inline assembly or write assembly proc, but you may use compiler intrinsics as well. You can even let compiler vectorize the loop, but it is sometimes difficult to write proper loop to be vectorized by compiler.

2) Make it parallel. Try using OpenMP.

Comment: @Leg, if you compile with `-O3` GCC should vectorize `c[count]+=a[count1]*b[count2]`.